# How can retrieve numbers of records above and under mean\median over time data with respect to time resolution in python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, bokeh

Let's say I have the following time [data](https://github.com/amcs1729/Predicting-cloud-CPU-usage-on-Azure-data/blob/master/azure.csv) for 1 month or (31 days) in January:

```py
import os, holoviews as hv
os.environ['HV_DOC_HTML'] = 'true'
hv.extension('bokeh')

import pandas as pd
import pandas_bokeh
from pandas_bokeh import plot_bokeh
pandas_bokeh.output_notebook()

#-----------------------------------------------------------
# Libs
#-----------------------------------------------------------
#!pip install hvplot
#!pip install pandas-bokeh

#-----------------------------------------------------------
# LOAD THE DATASET
#-----------------------------------------------------------

df = pd.read_csv('azure.csv')
df['timestamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.rename(columns={'min cpu': 'min_cpu',
                        'max cpu': 'max_cpu',
                        'avg cpu': 'avg_cpu',})
#df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df.head()


# Data preparation
# ==============================================================================
sliced_df = df[['timestamp', 'avg_cpu']]
# convert column to datetime object
#sliced_df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(sliced_df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# get the hour, day month
sliced_df['hour']        = sliced_df['timestamp'].dt.hour
sliced_df['day']         = sliced_df['timestamp'].dt.day
sliced_df['month']       = sliced_df['timestamp'].dt.month
sliced_df['year']        = sliced_df['timestamp'].dt.year

year_input=2017
month_input=1
day_input=21

# Retrive average CPU usage for hourly
df_avg = sliced_df.groupby('hour').agg({'avg_cpu': 'mean'}).reset_index()
df_21  = sliced_df[(sliced_df.year == year_input) & (sliced_df.month == month_input) & (sliced_df.day == day_input)]


df_21 = df_21.groupby('hour').agg({'avg_cpu': 'max'}).reset_index()

df_above = pd.merge(df_21, df_avg, on='hour', suffixes=('_hour','_avg'))
df_above['above']       = df_above.loc[df_above[f"avg_cpu_hour"] >= df_above["avg_cpu_avg"], f"avg_cpu_hour"]
df_above['above_value'] = df_above['avg_cpu_hour'] - df_above['avg_cpu_avg']

df_below = pd.merge(df_21, df_avg, on='hour', suffixes=('_hour','_avg'))
df_below['below']       = df_below.loc[df_below[f"avg_cpu_hour"] < df_below["avg_cpu_avg"], f"avg_cpu_hour"]
df_below['below_value'] = df_below['avg_cpu_hour'] - df_below['avg_cpu_avg']


above_count = df_above['above'].value_counts().sum()
below_count = df_below['below'].value_counts().sum()


dark_red = "#FF5555"
dark_blue = "#5588FF"


plot      = sliced_df.hvplot(     x="hour",       y="avg_cpu", by="day",  color="grey", alpha=0.02, legend=False, hover=False)
plot_avg  =    df_avg.hvplot(     x="hour",       y="avg_cpu",             color="grey",             legend=False)
plot_21th =    df_21.hvplot(      x="hour",       y="avg_cpu",             color="black",            legend=False)

plot_above = df_above.hvplot.area(x="hour", y="avg_cpu_avg", y2="avg_cpu_hour").opts(fill_alpha=0.2, line_alpha=0.8, line_color=dark_red, fill_color=dark_red)
plot_below = df_below.hvplot.area(x="hour", y="avg_cpu_avg", y2="avg_cpu_hour").opts(fill_alpha=0.2, line_alpha=0.8, line_color=dark_blue, fill_color=dark_blue)

text_days_above = hv.Text(5, df_21["avg_cpu"].max(), f"{above_count}", fontsize=14).opts(text_align="right", text_baseline="bottom", text_color=dark_red, text_alpha=0.8)
text_days_below = hv.Text(5, df_21["avg_cpu"].max(), f"{below_count}", fontsize=14).opts(text_align="right", text_baseline="top", text_color=dark_blue, text_alpha=0.8)

text_above      = hv.Text(5, df_21["avg_cpu"].max(), "DAYS ABOVE", fontsize=7).opts(text_align="left", text_baseline="bottom", text_color="lightgrey", text_alpha=0.8)
text_below      = hv.Text(5, df_21["avg_cpu"].max(), "DAYS BELOW", fontsize=7).opts(text_align="left", text_baseline="above", text_color="lightgrey", text_alpha=0.8)

hv.renderer("bokeh").theme = theme

final = (
    plot
    * plot_21th
    * plot_avg
    * plot_above
    * plot_below
    * text_days_above
    * text_days_below
    * text_above
    * text_below
).opts(
    xlabel="hourly",
    ylabel="CPU [Hz]",
    title=f"{day_input}th Jan data vs AVERAGE",
    gridstyle={"ygrid_line_alpha": 0},
    xticks=[
        (0, "00:00"),
        (1, "01:00"),
        (2, "02:00"),
        (3, "03:00"),
        (4, "04:00"),
        (5, "05:00"),
        (6, "06:00"),
        (7, "07:00"),
        (8, "08:00"),
        (9, "09:00"),
        (10, "10:00"),
        (11, "11:00"),
        (12, "12:00"),
        (13, "13:00"),
        (14, "14:00"),
        (15, "15:00"),
        (16, "16:00"),
        (17, "17:00"),
        (18, "18:00"),
        (19, "19:00"),
        (20, "20:00"),
        (21, "21:00"),
        (22, "22:00"),
        (23, "23:00"),
    ],
    xrotation=45,
    show_grid=True,
    fontscale=1.18,
)
hv.save(final, "final.html")

final
```

---

Update II:

I have tried the following code unsuccessfully inspired by the answer of @chitown88 using [bokeh](/questions/tagged/bokeh) instead of [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) package to get the desired output for *output1* at least.
My current output:
[image: img]

---

Example output for years:
[image: img]

As seen in the above example, I want to retrieve, reflect, and visualize my data in **smaller time resolution (hourly\daily\monthly)** rather than annually. I need to retrieve the number of CPU usage of column `avg cpu` within dataframe observations that exceeding\below:

- Output1:

> the **hourly** average for one certain day ( i.e., 21st Jan. 2024-01-21 00:00:00 till 2024-01-22 00:00:00)
>
> - x-axis: hourly timestamp of records for 21 Jan
> - y-axis: 'avg CPU' usage for 21 Jan
> - Threshold line: average CPU usage for 21 Jan

- Output2:

> The **daily** average for Jan.
>
> - x-axis: daily timestamp of Jan (1th-31th)
> - y-axis: 'avg CPU' usage for Jan
> - Threshold line: average CPU usage for Jan month

What is the elegant way to treat my dataframe to achieve this and the find threshold for interested *outpu1* and *output2* accordingly?

[image: img]

Comment: The CSV at the link only contains 2017 data so I wasn't able to reproduce the code - if you have a more complete CSV that would help.

Comment: @MuhammedYunus thanks for your comment. True I'm trying to adapt this csv data (1-month data in 2017) for the smaller time resolution explained for *output1* and *output2* in the post. I don't have complete annual data and not part of the interest of my problem for csv dataset at the moment. should we extract `dayofmonth`, `month`, `year` for my case from `timestamp` column in df?

Comment: You can use `df['hour'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour` to get the hour, and `df['month'] = df['timestamp'].dt.month` for the month.

Comment: That's right so you think we need to extract them from timestamp. Then what is your proposal on `df_avg` for *output1* and *output2* scenarios? why were they treated in main code `merge()` for retrieve `df_above` and `df_below`. What is the point of merging from your point of view?

Comment: To filter it to Jan `df = df.drop(index=df.index[df.timestamp.dt.month != 1])`. Then, to get the hour-by-hour average over all previous 21st Jan: `df_avg = df.loc[df.year.between(1990, 2020) & df.dayofyear.eq(21)].groupby('hour').mean()`. The `merge` is to combine both the 2023 and `df_avg` values into a single wider dataframe, with the suffixes `_2023` and `_avg` to indicate which dataframe the column came from.

Comment: Can you please provide the input as code to form a [mre]?

Comment: I meant code with DataFrame constructors (`pd.DataFrame(...)`) to set up the data

Comment: @mozway I re-updated and included the complete code for *Read\load data* and *data preparation*.

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464), one cannot reproduce data with `read_csv` and an unknown file ;)

Comment: @mozway I did my best and generated time data similar to the shared [dataset](https://github.com/amcs1729/Predicting-cloud-CPU-usage-on-Azure-data/blob/master/azure.csv) in csv. Plz see the *Update I* at the end of the post. :) But I couldn't manage to create a good fluctuated data\signal like shared dataset varatices' frequency.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, do you want just the two numbers `17` and `7` per each day? Or do you want to reproduce the plot for each day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try something more concrete:

```
# read data
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amcs1729/Predicting-cloud-CPU-usage-on-Azure-data/master/azure.csv')

# parse date time
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.normalize()
df['hour'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour

# store the hourly average for the entire dataset
hourly_avg = df.groupby('hour')['avg_cpu'].mean()

# compute the max by hour-date
max_hour_daily = df.groupby(['date', 'hour'])['avg_cpu'].max().unstack('hour')

# compare these maxes to the hourly_avg
# convert to DataFrame for easy manipulation
labels = pd.DataFrame(np.where(max_hour_daily.ge(hourly_avg, axis=1), 'above', 'below'), 
                      columns=max_hour_daily.columns, 
                      index=max_hour_daily.index)

# the expected output - a dataframe
# indexed by the date, with columns being `above`, `below`
output = labels.stack().groupby(level='date').value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Sample output:

```
# first five days
print(output.head())
```

Output:

```
            above  below
date                    
2017-01-01     13     11
2017-01-02     22      2
2017-01-03     21      3
2017-01-04     24      0
2017-01-05     16      8
```

Or you can get data for a specific day

```
# yes, string date works with `loc`
print(output.loc['2017-01-21'])
```

Output:

```
above    17
below     7
Name: 2017-01-21 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

---

If you want the plot, it's pretty straightforward from the DataFrames/Series above:

```
day = '2017-01-21'
day_max_hourly = max_hour_daily.loc[day]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.fill_between(day_max_hourly.index, day_max_hourly, hourly_avg, where=day_max_hourly >= hourly_avg, facecolor='red', interpolate=True, alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(day_max_hourly.index, day_max_hourly, hourly_avg, where=day_max_hourly < hourly_avg, facecolor='blue', interpolate=True, alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(hourly_avg, label='Hourly Average', color='black')
plt.plot(day_max_hourly, label='Max Hourly', color='green')
plt.xlabel('Hour')
plt.xticks(hourly_avg.index)
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your input can you extend your answer for *output2* as it is mentioned in the bounty description preferably use [bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/) package. How one can manipulate dataframe to reach *output2* -= daily average

Answer (score 2):

I think there needs to be a clearer in your ask here. As to look at `the daily average for one certain day ( i.e., 21st Jan. 2024-01-21 00:00:00 till 2024-01-22 00:00:00)` is actually wanting a an hourly average. And your `The monthly average for Jan.` is actually a daily average for January.

I'll provide for you the hourly average for a day. You can work out from their the other views you want. you'll need to decide how the averages/mean are calculated.

You can also play with the colors and aesthetics.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/SchvaJ01/Downloads/azure.csv')
df['timestamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])


# get the hour, day month
df['hour']  = df['timestamp'].dt.hour
df['dayofyear']   = df['timestamp'].dt.day
df['month'] = df['timestamp'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['timestamp'].dt.year


def daily_analysis(df, year_input, month_input, day_input):
    # get hourly average and specific day
    # Group by hour, and calculate the max of 'max cpu' and min of 'min cpu' for each hour
    df_avg = df.groupby('hour').agg({'max cpu': 'mean'}).reset_index()
    df_day = df[(df.year == year_input) & (df.month == month_input) & (df.dayofyear == day_input)]
    
    df_day = df_day.groupby('hour').agg({'max cpu': 'max'}).reset_index()
    
    df_above_below = pd.merge(df_day, df_avg, on='hour', suffixes=('_hour','_avg'))
    df_above_below['above_below'] = df_above_below.apply(lambda row: 'above' if row['max cpu_hour'] > row['max cpu_avg'] else 'below', axis=1)
    df_above_below['above_below_value'] = df_above_below['max cpu_hour'] - df_above_below['max cpu_avg']


    above_count = df_above_below['above_below'].value_counts()['above']
    below_count = df_above_below['above_below'].value_counts()['below']

    df_graph = df_above_below.copy()

    sns.set_style("darkgrid", {"axes.facecolor": "#A9A9A9"})  # Setting the background to a specific hex color

    
    plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))
    
    # Applying a polynomial regression with seaborn lineplot for smoothing
    sns.lineplot(x='hour', y='max cpu_hour', data=df_graph, color='white', label='Max CPU Hour', marker='', sort=False, errorbar=None, estimator=None)
    sns.lineplot(x='hour', y='max cpu_avg', data=df_graph, color='lightblue', label='Max CPU Avg', marker='', sort=False, errorbar=None, estimator=None)
    
    # Calculating the smoothed values for filling
    # Since seaborn does not directly support filling between lines with regression fits, we revert to the original method for demonstration
    plt.fill_between(df_graph['hour'], df_graph['max cpu_hour'], df_graph['max cpu_avg'], 
                     where=(df_graph['max cpu_hour'] >= df_graph['max cpu_avg']), facecolor='green', interpolate=True, alpha=0.3)
    plt.fill_between(df_graph['hour'], df_graph['max cpu_hour'], df_graph['max cpu_avg'], 
                     where=(df_graph['max cpu_hour'] < df_graph['max cpu_avg']), facecolor='red', interpolate=True, alpha=0.3)
    
    # Customizing the plot with dark theme adjustments
    plt.title(f'Hourly Max CPU Comparison with Average {year_input}-{month_input}-{day_input}\nData Above: {above_count}\nData Below: {below_count}', color='black', fontsize=16)
    plt.xlabel('Hour', color='black')
    plt.ylabel('Max CPU', color='black')
    plt.xticks(df_graph['hour'], color='black')
    plt.yticks(color='black')
    plt.legend()
    
    plt.show()
    
    
    
daily_analysis(df, 2017, 1, 21)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution. would you extend it for both scenarios *output1* and *output2*. You're right at the biting of your answer therefore I included an expected picture for further clarification. Something is missing which is not reflecting the count of days above/below the mean curve.

Comment: You now have the general code/framework to produce the hourly. You can adapt the code to get the daily on a month level. Give it a shot on your own first, and if you run into an issue or error, then post a new question. You need to some amount of work/effort - stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: sure thing I'm familiar with it. Since I have written in the bounty description: "*I expect to transform address time data within dataframe to reach the example plot for output1 and output2 which are for smaller time resolution.*", I asked for. You are right.

Comment: Certainly if I get time, I'll tweak and embellish. But this should at least get you started and headed into a direction.