# How to duplicate rows based on the number of weeks between two dates?

Tags: python, pandas

My input is this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ID': ['ID001', 'ID002', 'ID003'],
        'DATE': ['24/12/2023', '01/02/2024', '12/02/2024'],
    }
)

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], dayfirst=True)

print(df)

      ID       DATE
0  ID001 2023-12-24
1  ID002 2024-02-01
2  ID003 2024-02-12
```

I'm trying to duplicate the rows for each id N times with N being the number of weeks between the column `DATE` and the current date. At the end, each last row for a given id will have the week of the column `DATE`.

For that I made the code below but it gives me a wrong output :

```
number_of_weeks = (pd.Timestamp('now') - df['DATE']).dt.days // 7

final = df.copy()
final['YEAR'] = final['DATE'].dt.isocalendar().year
final['WEEK'] = final['DATE'].dt.isocalendar().week
final['WEEKS'] = (pd.Timestamp('now') - df['DATE']).dt.days // 7

for index, row in final.iterrows():
    for i in range(1, row['WEEKS'] + 1):
        final.loc[i, 'WEEK'] = i

final = final.ffill().drop(columns='WEEKS')

print(final)

      ID       DATE  YEAR  WEEK
0  ID001 2023-12-24  2023    51
1  ID002 2024-02-01  2024     1
2  ID003 2024-02-12  2024     2
3  ID003 2024-02-12  2024     3
4  ID003 2024-02-12  2024     4
5  ID003 2024-02-12  2024     5
6  ID003 2024-02-12  2024     6
7  ID003 2024-02-12  2024     7
```

Have you guys encountered a similar problem ? I'm open to any suggestion.

My expected output is this :

```
       ID        DATE  YEAR   WEEK
0   ID001  24/12/2023  2023     51
1   ID001  24/12/2023  2023     52
2   ID001  24/12/2023  2024      1
3   ID001  24/12/2023  2024      2
4   ID001  24/12/2023  2024      3
5   ID001  24/12/2023  2024      4
6   ID001  24/12/2023  2024      5
7   ID001  24/12/2023  2024      6
8   ID001  24/12/2023  2024      7
##################################
9   ID002  01/02/2024  2024      5
10  ID002  01/02/2024  2024      6
11  ID002  01/02/2024  2024      7
##################################
12  ID003  12/02/2024  2024      7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use periods for that and [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html):

```
# compute exact difference in weeks
n_weeks = (df['DATE'].dt.to_period('W')
           .rsub(pd.Timestamp('now').to_period('W'))
           .apply(lambda x: x.n)
          )

# repeat rows, add incrementing days, convert to week number
out = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(n_weeks+1)]
         .assign(WEEK=lambda d: df['DATE']
                 .add(pd.to_timedelta(d.groupby(level=0).cumcount()*7, unit='D'))
                 .dt.isocalendar().week
                )
      )
```

Output:

```
      ID       DATE  WEEK
0  ID001 2023-12-24    51
0  ID001 2023-12-24    52
0  ID001 2023-12-24     1
0  ID001 2023-12-24     2
0  ID001 2023-12-24     3
0  ID001 2023-12-24     4
0  ID001 2023-12-24     5
0  ID001 2023-12-24     6
0  ID001 2023-12-24     7
1  ID002 2024-02-01     5
1  ID002 2024-02-01     6
1  ID002 2024-02-01     7
2  ID003 2024-02-12     7
```

Comment: Would you consider my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77994714/10452700) kindly?