# How to make pandas dataframe long to wide

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot

Here is the input dataframe.
**Case 1:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'order': {0: '1',
  1: '1',
  2: '2',
  3: '2',
  4: '3',
  5: '3'},
 'start': {0: pd.Timestamp('2023-04-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  1: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  2: pd.Timestamp('2023-04-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  3: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  4: pd.Timestamp('2023-04-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  5: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')},
 'end': {0: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  1: pd.Timestamp('2023-06-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  2: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  3: pd.Timestamp('2023-06-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  4: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  5: pd.Timestamp('2023-06-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')},
 'quant': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50},
 'price': {0: 44, 1: 44, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 8}})
```

input df image - >[input df image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfuMw.png)

My requirement is to wide this dataframe based on **order** , So my expected output is
[expected df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXj1y.png)

**Case 2:**

```
`
  df = pd.DataFrame({'order': {0: '1',
  1: '1',
  2: '2',
  3: '2',
  4: '3',
  5: '3',
  6: '3',
  7: '3'},
 'start': {0: pd.Timestamp('2023-04-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  1: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  2: pd.Timestamp('2023-04-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  3: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  4: pd.Timestamp('2023-04-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  5: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  6: pd.Timestamp('2023-03-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  7: pd.Timestamp('2023-02-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')},
 'end': {0: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  1: pd.Timestamp('2023-06-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  2: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  3: pd.Timestamp('2023-06-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  4: pd.Timestamp('2023-05-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  5: pd.Timestamp('2023-06-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  6: pd.Timestamp('2023-04-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  7: pd.Timestamp('2023-03-01 04:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')},
 'quant': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6:10, 7:10},
 'price': {0: 44, 1: 44, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 8, 6:9, 7:8}})`
```

In this case we have two more rows for order 3. So resulting dataframe quant & price should be Nan for order 1 & 2 for extra rows of order 3.

input frame ->
[input df image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef0nT.png)

expected output is,
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYnC5.png)

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), you can then reorder the levels:

```
out = (df.pivot(index=['start', 'end'], columns='order')
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
         .swaplevel(axis=1)
      )
```

Output:

```
order                                                   1           2           3      
                                                    quant price quant price quant price
start                     end                                                          
2023-04-01 04:00:00+00:00 2023-05-01 04:00:00+00:00    10    44    20     5    40     8
2023-05-01 04:00:00+00:00 2023-06-01 04:00:00+00:00    10    44    30     6    50     8
```

Comment: Thanks for the shortest solution. Can you please also look into the Case 2 ?

Comment: @Ranjith I don't get the difference, the same code should give the expected output for case 2

Comment: @mozway Would you mind to check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77994714/10452700) with bounty if you're free?

Answer (score 0):

First, try not to use `input` as a variable. It's a predefined function in python.

To do widen this dataframe, set your start and end as the index. Then unstack based on the `'order'` column.

```
# Convert 'start' and 'end' to datetime
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

# Setting 'start' and 'end' as the index and 'order' as a column level
df.set_index(['start', 'end', 'order'], inplace=True)

# Unstack 'order' to make it a top-level column
df_unstacked = df.unstack(level='order')


# Creating multi-level columns for 'quant' and 'price' per 'order'
df_wide = df_unstacked.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).reset_index(drop=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df_wide.to_string())
order                     start                       end     1           2           3      
                                                          price quant price quant price quant
0     2023-04-01 04:00:00+00:00 2023-05-01 04:00:00+00:00    44    10     5    20     8    40
1     2023-05-01 04:00:00+00:00 2023-06-01 04:00:00+00:00    44    10     6    30     8    50
```

Comment: Hi @chitown88 , Thanks for the solution. But I need order in the first row as I shown in the expected df for each price, quant pair. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXj1y.png

Comment: @chitown88 , I appreciate your efforts :). Can you please also look into the Case 2 ?